# Running Xvfb and CutyCapt as Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, xvfb, cutycapt

I'm an trying to take a screenshot in the background using [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)

My application is written in python and calls CutyCapt by running a subprocess.

Works locally (windows) just fine, but the CutyCapt.exe for windows does not require an x server.  When I try to execute my code (via the python subprocess) on my ubuntu box, it barks about me not supplying a command to Xvfb. However, if I run the command on the box myself it works fine.

Command that works on box:

```
box$ xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1100x800x24" ./CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.com --out=temp.png
```

Python Code that fails:

```
def url_screengrab(url, **kwargs):
    url, temp_path, filename, url_hash = get_temp_screengrab_info(url)
    args = []
    if sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
        args.append('xvfb-run')
        args.append('--server-args="-screen 0, 1100x800x24"')
    args.append(settings.CUTYCAPT_EXE_PATH)
    args.append('--url=%s' % (url))
    args.append('--out=%s' % (temp_path,))
    subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False)
    return temp_path, filename, url_hash
```

Returned error:

```
xvfb-run: usage error: need a command to run
box$
```

Things I've tried:
-using call instead of Popen
-stripping the quote from the screen args
-breaking the screen args up into a list
-setting os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":0" before executing the subprocess

Do I need to break the xvfb process up from the CutyCapt command?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `shell = True`, then the first argument to `Popen` should be a string, not a list. When `shell = False` (the default), the first argument should be a list. Have you tried it with `shell = False`?

Comment: If `settings.PLATFORM` is not `"linux"`, how is `xvfb-run` getting appended to `args`?

Comment: Instead of manually building args, try `import shlex; args = shlex.split(''' xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1100x800x24" ./CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.com --out=temp.png ''')`.

Comment: @ubuntu - i dont need to run xvfb on windows (locally)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Ubuntu 11.10, with the cutycapt and xvfb packages installed, the following works (at least for me...):

```
import shlex
import subprocess

def url_screengrab(url, **kwargs):
    cmd = '''xvfb-run --server-args "-screen 0, 1100x800x24"
             /usr/bin/cutycapt --url={u} --out=temp.png '''.format(u = url)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
    proc.communicate()

url = 'http://www.google.com'
url_screengrab(url)
```

Comment: that works, thx. is there anything I have to do to guarantee shut down of the subprocess, as it seems my next line of code can't access the `temp.png` file even though it created it correctly?

Comment: `proc.communicate()` will block until the subprocess completes.

Comment: @MattoTodd can you please explain how did you shut down the subprocess?